# Does Powershell have a feature like Bash's "autocd" shopt?

Tags: bash, powershell, command-line, shopt

Does powershell have a feature like bash's autocd shopt?

If you enable that in bash you can navigate into folders by typing out their name.

For example if you have a folder called "foo" in your current directory and you type out `foo` it would execute `cd foo` instead.

Comment: I've never seen such functionality within Powershell, it's a very different beast to bash under the hood. You could however install the [Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and use bash within Windows.

Comment: I already have a variety of bash based shells installed. I'm trying to give powershell a little bit more appreciation currently. 

Would it be possible to hook the error message it gives when you try to execute something it can't find? For example if I type "bar" and it spews the usual error if I can trap that I can list the current folder's contents and CD into what the user typed myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone's still looking for this, I've put an implementation [here](https://github.com/nickcox/cd-extras) and on the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/cd-extras/). It includes several other niceties from bash such as CD_PATH, improved tab completion for directory paths and `cd-`, `cd+`.

Comment: This is seriously awesome! Thanks